# Why QR Code scanner doesn't work from angle in Android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera, qr-code

I was trying QR Code scanner in a React Native project. I have used these two libraries -

https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner

https://github.com/ekreutz/react-native-barcode-scanner-google

Both of these libraries doesn't scan QR Code from an angle. Phone should be exactly in front of QR Code then only it scans. However, same library works very fast and from any angle in iOS. Is it a limitation of android camera? Can we do something to achieve same behaviour in Android too?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while developing barcode scanner for my app, I tried different libraries for Android, however [Mobile vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview)(API developed by Google) pretty much solved this problem for me. Give it a try

Comment: thanks for the reply, react-native-barcode-scanner-google is a react native wrapper for Vision API. I have tried but it more or less works same.